# navbar no muestra contenido debajo

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Creé un navbar bastante basico con angular material, pero me di cuenta que al agregar un div debajo de este para agregar algun contenido que quiera imprimir, no se visualiza ya que esta detrás del navbar, es decir en vez de que mi contenido empiece al final del navbar, lo que esta haciendo es imprimirse detras del navbar y posicionándose hasta el "top" pero detras del navbar.

Algo así es lo que sucede, está tomando el ejemplo B, en vez del A, como ven se imprimie mi div de contenido detras del navbar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.mat-toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 24px;
    background: white;
    line-height: 24px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="basic-container ">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isOpen">
        <div>
            <p>Show test</p>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: `mat-toolbar` no es una clase. ¿No deberías escribir el selector sin punto? Puede que esté equivocado, no sé de angular.

Comment: Deberías crear un ejemplo reproducible, porque la verdad tu código no dice mucho para poder ver el problema

Comment: Normalmente los componentes de angular-material suelen añadir una clase con su propio nombre, en este caso sería válido usar `.mat-toolbar` como clase, pues el componente mat-toolbar tiene la clase `mat-toolbar`. De todas maneras, yo prefiere usar los nombres de los componentes directamente, puesto que visualmente me ayuda a ver claramente qué es un div/span/lo-que-sea y qué es un componente, pero ser, es válido usar sus clases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en que has puesto la *position* de tu mat-toolbar a *fixed*. Esto la sacará del flujo principal y por eso el div quedará debajo.

Como supongo que lo que quieres hacer es que la toolbar quede fijada en la parte superior y el *basic-container* pueda hacer scroll, lo que yo haría sería envolverlo todo en un div de tipo flex y luego hacer la toolbar un elemento flex de ancho fijo y el *basic-container* un flex de ancho variable hasta el resto del contenedor padre y con propiedad de overflow en auto.

Observa que pongo el alto del body y el del contenedor padre a 100%.

Quito algunas propiedades de tu clase *mat-toolbar* por ser innecesarias.

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

.contenedor{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.mat-toolbar {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  padding: 20px 24px;
  background: white;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.basic-container{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

y la vista

```
<div class="contenedor">
  <mat-toolbar>
    <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <div class="basic-container">
      TU CODIGO
  </div>
</div>
```